# How to Read Data Number by Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field that contains numbers such as the examples below in #Numbers. Each number within each row in #Numbers relates
to many different values that are contained within the #Area table.

I need to make a relationship from #Numbers to #Area using each number within each row.

```
CREATE TABLE #Numbers
(
    Number int
)

INSERT INTO #Numbers
(
    Number
)

SELECT 102 UNION
SELECT 1 UNION
SELECT 2 UNION

select * from #Numbers

CREATE TABLE #Area
(
    Number int,
    Area varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Area
(
    Number,
    Area
)
SELECT 0,'Area1' UNION
SELECT 1,'Area2' UNION
SELECT 1,'Area3' UNION
SELECT 1,'Area5' UNION
SELECT 1,'Area8' UNION
SELECT 1,'Area9' UNION
SELECT 2,'Area12' UNION
SELECT 2,'Area43' UNION
SELECT 2,'Area25' UNION

select * from #Area
```

It would return the following for 102:

```
102,Area2    
102,Area3    
102,Area5    
102,Area8    
102,Area9    
102,Area1     
102,Area12    
102,Area43    
102,Area25
```

For 1 it would return:

```
1,Area2    
1,Area3    
1,Area5    
1,Area8    
1,Area9
```

For 2 it would return:

```
2,Area12    
2,Area43
2,Area25
```

Note how the numbers match up to the individual Areas and return the values accordingly.

Comment: can you please provide a definite example. your OP is quite confusing. regards

Comment: Sorry @maSTAShuFu, have edited. Is that clearer?

Comment: @Philip . . . Not at all.  What is "Area1" and so on?  That is not in the data at all.  Nor are the relationships.

Comment: Sorry Gordon, it isn't in the relationship, because it isn't contained in the database. Rather than returning the actual numbers, I need to return the actual allocated Area Numbers, e.g. 1 allocates to Area1, Area2, Area7, Area8, Area15

Comment: @Philip .. do you have another table with Area1 etc etc?  I can only assume from your desired result that you are after a concatenation of the "Area..." values for the corresponding integer position.. where each Integer has a predefined "Area" list. is that correct?

Comment: Hi @Harry, yes that's exactly correct. Each integer has a defined list of Areas it is associated to. I don't have that information within the database, but I suppose it could be a temp table? Shall I update the question with the list?

Comment: Having a single column where each digit of the column's value carries a different piece of information is not ideal.

Comment: Still have no idea why "1" returns area 1,2,7,8 and 15. I can't see any pattern. If the integer 1 means an area, why isn't it related to every number row that starts with "1"?

Comment: @TomC - I think each digit represents a set of areas, so 12 is the union of the set associated with 1 and the set associated with 2.

Comment: @TomC I don't think it matters what the pattern is.. the OP just wants to replace the value 1 with the corresponding Area values and 2 with its own etc etc..

Comment: Really sorry for the confusion guys. I have updated the question with the Area list defined. Hopefully the example is clear.

Comment: @Philip - I think the questions just got more confusing with your latest Edit.. I thought I understood the question.. but looking at it now.. I don't any more!

Comment: Philip, you need to post a MUCH smaller sample.  You also need to post desired output.  See [ask] and [mcve] for further details.

Comment: @Harry, Brian - have edited the question again trying to make it as clear as possible. Is that better?

Comment: Do you know what is the different between working design and great design?!? A working design solve your current needs, while great design solve your future needs (these who you do not know about yet). Your design seems in first glance like awful. It lead to poor performance and does not have any flexibly. Regarding the future, you are limited to 10 types of whatever you call it a "number" since you use base 10 and you split the result according to the characters of the value. I RECOMMEND YOU NOT TO SPEND TIME ON SOLVING CURRENT REQUEST. INSTEAD YOU SHOULD REDESIGN YOUR SYSTEM from scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you need to extract individual digit from `#Number` and then used it to join to `#Area`

```
; with tally as
(
    select  n = 1
    union all
    select  n = n + 1
    from    tally
    where   n < 10
)
select  n.Number, a.Area
from    #Numbers n
        cross apply
        (
            -- here it convert n.Number to string
            -- then extract 1 digit
            -- and finally convert back to integer
            select  num = convert(int, 
                                  substring(convert(varchar(10), n.Number),
                                            t.n, 
                                            1) 
                                  )
            from    tally t
            where   t.n <= len(convert(varchar(10), n.Number))
        ) d
        inner join #Area a  on  d.num = a.Number
order by n.Number
```

or if you prefer to do it in arithmetic and not string

```
; with Num as
(
    select  Number, n = 0, Num = Number / power(10, 0) % 10
    from    #Numbers

    union all

    select  Number, n = n + 1, Num = Number / power(10, n + 1) % 10
    from    Num
    where   Number  > power(10, n + 1)
)
select  n.Number, a.Area
from    Num n
    inner join #Area a  on  n.Num   = a.Number
order by n.Number
```

Comment: Thanks very much Squirrel, that did exactly as I needed.

Comment: There is no need to `extract individual digit from #Number`. You can simply treat the numbers as string and use simple a "like" filter (check my solution below).

Comment: Why a cross apply and not a simple join, `join tally t on t.n <=len(convert(varchar,n.number))` and then `join #Area a  on  a.number = substring(convert(varchar,n.number),t.n,1)`

Comment: not really any much difference in this case. Just a matter of preference. I like my JOIN condition clean

Answer (score 3):

Well, the OP marked an answer already, which even got votes. Maybe he will not read this, but here is another option using direct simple select, which (according to the EP) seems like using a lot less resources:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Numbers t1
LEFT JOIN #Area t2 ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t1.Number) like '%' + CONVERT(CHAR(1), t2.Number) + '%'
GO
```

> **Note!** According to Execution Plan this solution uses only 27% while the selected answer (written by Squirrel) uses 73%, **but** Execution Plan can be misleading sometimes and *you should check IO and TIME statistics as well* using the real table structure and real data.

Comment: Simple is nice, but more important is the performance that you gain. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea. In theory, it should work. 
Have a table (temp or permanent) with the values and it's translation

I.E.

```
ID   value
1    Area1, Area2, Area7, Area8, Area15
2    Area28, Area35
```

etc

Take each row and put a some special character between each number. Use a function like string_split with that character to turn it into a column of values.

e.g 0123 will then be something like 0|1|2|3 and when you run that through string_split you would get

```
0
1
2
3
```

Now join each value to your lookup table and return the Value.

Now you have a row with all the values that you want. Use another function like STUFF FOR XML and put those values back into a single column.

This doesn't sound very efficient.. but this is one way of achieving what you desire..

Another is to do a `replace()`.. but that would be very messy!

Answer (score 0):

Create a third table called n which contains a single column also called n that contains integers from 1 to the maximum number of digits in your number. Make it 1000 if you like, doesn't matter. Then:

```
select #numbers.number, substring(convert(varchar,#numbers.number),n,1) as chr, Area 
from #numbers
join n on n>0 and n <=len(convert(varchar,number))
join #area on #area.number=substring(convert(varchar,#numbers.number),n,1)
```

The middle column chr is just there to show you what it's doing, and would be removed from the final result.